# Merging files in different clearcase branches in Eclipse

Tags: eclipse, merge, clearcase, ibm-rational

I am working in a project where we use Clearcase for version control. Here, along with the main branch, release specific branches are created. Sometimes, it may happen that we have to modify a file and sync it in all the branches. For this we maintain different workspace in Eclipse having different config spec, and then we go to each workspace to manually check in the same file in all the branches. It is very much time consuming and erroneous process as we may miss some files. Is there any way to  merge the files using Eclipse Clearcase plugin?

Please note I am using Eclipse Clearcase plugin for checkiin/checkout and do not have access to Cleartool.

Answer (score 0):

> Please note I am using Eclipse clearcase plugin for checkiin/checkout and do not have access to cleartool.

The only reason you don't have access to cleartool is if you are using a CCRC 7.1 or a ClearTeam 8.0.

In any case, the main reason you have to maintain different Eclipse workspace (which are time consuming to switch to) is because an Eclipse workspace cannot load in a project explorer more than one project with the same name.

One solution would be to maintain *one dedicated* Eclipse workspace in which you have all your views (web views or dynamic views) referenced by the ClearTeam Navigator view, but *not* loaded as Eclipse project (ie, you cannot compile those project with Eclipse).

[image: http://www-01.ibm.com/support/docview.wss?uid=swg24031012&aid=10]

In that dedicated workspace, you can then perform many merges in a row between views, without having to switch to a different workspace.